# LinkedIn Permissions / API : Display last article of an organization

Tags: php, linkedin-api, drupal-8

(Really sorry for my English, it's not my mother language)

We must display for a client, the last article published on their Linkedin page.
He gave me access to his account, and I was able to create an application linked to his page ("verified" link).
In the "Auth" tab of the application, I was able to recover "Client ID" and "Client Secret".

Now I need to authenticate with OAuth 2.0, but I don't understand what I need to do.
Should I go through a "3-legged OAuth" or a "2-legged OAuth"?
I have the impression that the second option is the best, because, if I understood correctly, it does not require manual authentication every X days.
Maybe I'm wrong?

I also read that I could go through the "Product" tab of the application and add the "Marketing Developer Platform". But is this really where I should orient myself?

As a reminder, the goal is, on an internet site (intranet to be exact), to put together the last article posted on the client's LinkedIn page.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need the **marketing development platform** access to do this add **marketing development platform** in your product list. But **it is not simple** as you think you have to fill the application after that you have to submit that for a review then you will know your result

Comment: Thanks Darkknight.
I will discuss this with my clients.
However, I have read that it will not be possible to use "Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth)" with marketing APIs.
How do I get past the manual authorization page? If it's possible ?

Comment: they shut down the version 1 so it's not possible I think